# replace more than white space with some value in python

Tags: python

I want to replace more than one white spaces from string with "@".
If one white space is there it should be intact but if there is more than one consecutive whitespace then it will keep one and append @. For example

```
s = "Hello how  are   you."
```

would become

```
"Hello how @are @@you"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 2.7:

```
import re
s = "Hello how  are   you"
s = re.sub("(?<= ) ", "@" ,s)

print s
```

Or, if you want to have only one **@** signifying "multiple spaces", change to `("(?<= ) +", "@" ,s)`

**Explanation**: The regex contains a positive lookbehind `(?<= )` : it only finds spaces that are preceded by another space, but does not include the first space in the results. Because of that, when the results are replaced by an @, the first space remains intact (it is not preceded by another one), all the others are replaced in a one-by-one fashion by @.

Adding `+` to the main expression means that it will collect all multiple spaces except for the first one (due to positive lookbehind) and replace them with a single @.

This pattern will only get the " ", if you want to cover tabs, too, you'd need to change to `\s`

Comment: This is a good answer, that would be improved if you provided a brief explanation of the regex.

Comment: @asongtoruin I added an explanation (as far as my understanding allowed)

Comment: @t.m.adam I disagree - it looks that way from the way OP's post is displayed, but if you go into "edit" you'll see it features multiple spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much, this what I exactly wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Having looked at the source of your question, my answer didn't fix it. I couldn't see the extra spaces in your source string. A regular expression as sg.sysel suggests will do the job nicely.

In case you did want to do it yourself with a loop:

```
def addats(s):
    i = 0
    r = ''
    for c in s:
        if c == ' ':
            if i > 0:
                r += '@'
            else:
                r += ' '
            i += 1
        else:
            r += c
            i = 0
    return r
```

Note that for a real application, you should use something mutable like a list instead of a string for `r` there, but this should solve your immediate problem.